# PySerial readline

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial

I connected STM processor with Raspberry Pi through serial port (Tx, Rx). I have two threads for managing data on serial port (sender, receiver). I use while True loop and PySerial functions (write, readline). Everything works fine if STM processor is working, even if the data are corrupted. The problem occurs when I do not get data when I expected them (when I do a short circuit on a connection or if STM processor fails). This is the worst case scenario, but I need to predict it because of software restart function. In a connection with threads I use queues and consequently I know when data were sent to STM processor and when I can expect the answer. So, if I do not get the answer, the code stuck at readline line. Is it possible to identify on RPi layer that something is wrong with the connection, STM processor? I do not get any exception or error. I need something like that ->

```
#receiver side

while True:

    if everything is ok: 
        serial_port.readilne()
    else:
        restart
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe you need to read byte-by-byte instead of reading the whole line, and use `inWaiting()`?

Comment: Are you using a timeout on your serial port initialization?  You should be able to get the readline to fail after a certain period of time and they simply retry.  http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline